# Predicting labels which are not independent of one another

Tags: multilabel-classification

I want to make a multilabel classifier where the labels are dependent on one another. Concretely, I have a situation where:

If label A is true, then label B is also true.

If label B is true, label A could be true or false.

If label B is false, then label A is false.

How can I model this in a multilabel classifier?

Answer (score 1):

In this case the easiest way is to use a simple single-label classifier with three labels:

- A0B1
- A1B1
- A0B0

As long as the number of combinations is reasonable, that's what will give the best results while satisfying the constraints.

By the way "If label B is false, then label A is false" is logically implied by "if label A is true, then label B is also true". (contrapositive).